# Is it possible to deal with optional properties that are conditional based on a boolean in the type?

Tags: typescript

My current situation is a server response with a boolean success and optional response data or error information.

```
type ServerResponse = {
  success: boolean;
  data?: { [key: string]: string };
  err?: { code: number, message: string };
}
```

When I want to deal with this type, it can be a bit awkward:

```
const resp: ServerResponse = await fetch(...);

if(resp.success) {
   doSomething( resp.data?.foo );
} else {
   handleErr( resp.err?.message );
}
```

It's annoying to have to use the `?` when I know that `data` will *always* be there when `success === true` and `err` will *always* be there when `success === false`

I've been trying to grok the [documentation on mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), but am not finding what I need.

Is the only or best way to do this by changing the approach to ignore `success`?

```
const resp: ServerResponse = await fetch(...);

if(resp.data) {
   doSomething( resp.data.foo );
} else if(resp.err) {
   handleErr( resp.err.message );
}
```

While that seems reasonable, I'd like to learn more advanced ways of typing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can model this using [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).

The code for your use case is shown below,

```
interface SuccessResponse {
    success: true;
    data: { [key: string]: string }
}

interface ErrorResponse {
    success: false;
    err: { code: number, message: string };
}

type ServerResponse = SuccessResponse | ErrorResponse;

fetch("http://your-endpoint.com")
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((jsonResponse: ServerResponse) => {
        if(jsonResponse.success) {
            console.log(jsonResponse.data)
        } else {
            console.log(jsonResponse.err)
        }
    })
```

[TS Playground Version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoFcFIM7YEoTYAOA9iNigN4CwAUAJDaY7YBcyYU6EA3HfQBM4YOO0rIA2gGsIAT3bZOoAOYBdBUpDLkAXzp7adUJFiIUAUShQSUAsTIVkNBkyyE2yeABsKfBtCgxZAQSAQh2EHQAWwAjaAAaZCj3OGVw5EUoFV0-AzowWSIUVGgAN2g7UnIUAF40ZndKhxQAH2RLa1tCKt86OhgIMAQACwAKACJhsDAiVgB6OdkSdCgAWggQAVJjADoQqPGASn4dsGGN0dGobubD5BqAPid+emuwFZBka-tqnYArbBkUaHPz0HTHBinc4gS4AshNarsEpQcpdH4UO6PZ4MejAGCjOEgBEUHauFh3Zz0KkhcgkLwQHZeEjKAmAok3X5CEQQqk6ZAQHxUF70GmA+mM5ms+EckkBHlg-jgoA)

Let me know if that's not clear.

Comment: Please consider supplementing your code link with a plaintext version as well.